# Category of chain complex and category of topological space

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology

Homology group is a functor from a category of chain complex to a category of abelian group.
And singular homology group is a functor from a category of topological space to a category of abelian group.

I want to prove

> category of chain complex is not equivalent category of topological space

It seems to me obvious in a certain way because we cannot replace every problem of topological space to a problem of chain complex.

But I don't know how to prove formally.Thank you.

Comment: Well, there are certain properties of categories that are preserved by equivalences. For example, whether or not there is a zero object.

Comment: I know category of topology space does not have zero object. Does the category of chain complex has zero object?

Comment: @bellow the chain complex that is 0 in every degree